# Using PropertyValue for ImageObject / Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

Example is from http://schema.org/ImageObject

```
  <div itemprop="exifData" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Exposure Time">
      <meta itemprop="value" content="1/659 sec.">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="exifData" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="FNumber">
      <meta itemprop="value" content="f/4.0">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="exifData" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="MaxApertureValue">
      <meta itemprop="value" content="2.00">
  </div>   
  <div itemprop="exifData" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Metering Mode">
      <meta itemprop="value" content="Pattern">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="exifData" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Flash">
      <meta itemprop="value" content="Flash did not fire.">
  </div>
```

These itemprop names and values are completely custom, right? My question is, is there a naming convention? Because MaxApertureValue in example is written as one word and in CamelCase, while Metering Mode is normal. Wouldn't it be better if I just put Aperture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s up to the author which names (i.e., values for the `name` property) to use. Of course it makes sense to use standard names, should they exist.

In this example, the author marks up the Exif data exactly like it’s specified in the file:

> ```
> <!-- We assume the following EXIF meta-data is available, but currently not shown:
> Exposure Time:    1/659 sec.
> FNumber:          f/4.0
> MaxApertureValue: 2.00
> Metering Mode:    Pattern
> Flash:            Flash did not fire.
> -->
> ```

I don’t know Exif, but [according to its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Example), the names seem to be written like that (i.e., `MaxApertureValue`, `Metering Mode` etc.).

So this is what consumers would likely expect for the `exifData` property.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will follow the convention like it is written on Wikipedia. Generally speaking (not for this EXIF), is it better to write names in english, even though the website is in french, italian etc.?

Comment: @BorisKozarac: Generally, I’d say no, you should typically use the language the content is in. But for things like Exif (which isn’t really natural language, but a collection of standardized names), it wouldn’t make sense to translate them because machines wouldn’t recognize them anymore. -- In the end, it always depends on which consumers you expect to make use of your data.